# Find out RSA padding using OpenSSL API

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I am using Openssl 1.0.1f to load private keys and using them to decrypt some data. This is the function that I am using:

```
RSA_private_decrypt
```

But it requires a parameter that is the padding. It could be be:

`RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`

`RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`

`RSA_SSLV23_PADDING`

Is there a way to find out which padding to use with OpenSSL API?

I mean, how to find out which padding is in use in some ciphertext. I have the private keys to decrypt the data, but I am not sure which one to use. Is there a way to get this information through the private keys using OpenSSL?

I do not know what parameters were used to encrypt.

Thanks!

Comment: Decrypt using each of them and see which is giving the correct result.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: starting with `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`.